# exclude a field with orika mapper

Tags: java, orika

I have 2 classes, `ClassA` and `ClassB`. I am using Orika Mapper to map all the fields in both classes.

```
mapperFactory.classMap(ClassA.class, ClassB.class).byDefault().register();
```

But there is a case where i want to exclude a field. Is there a way to do this when I do `mapper.map(...);` something like `mapper.map(classA, ClassB.class).exclude("fieldToExclude);`
or maybe declare another `mapperFactory.classMap` rule to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it exactly the way you suggested.

It's in the [documentation](https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/mappings-via-classmapbuilder.html):

```
mapperFactory.classMap(ClassA.class, ClassB.class)
    .exclude("fieldToExclude")
    ...
    .register();
```

Notice the field still needs to exist in both classes.

Comment: but if I do that, will override the other rule?
`mapperFactory.classMap(ClassA.class, ClassB.class).byDefault().register();` I need to use this mapping in other cases too.

Comment: You can combine them. Add `exclude` between `classMap` and `byDefault`.